# CSS 3D Transform - opening a card

Tags: javascript, css, css-transforms

I'm making a ecard. When the user clicks the card, it will open and show its contents. How do I make this in CSS and javascript? I am using perspective and rotation, as you can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pYJm6/1/). If you know an example that looks like what I'm trying to do, please post the link.

[image: Example: each color represents a different content.]

Comment: [This.](http://jsfiddle.net/pYJm6/) I can't figure out how to organize the divs.

Comment: @J.Morais - OK, try absolute positioning and z-index. This link (http://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_positioning.asp) has a nice explanation of positioning.

Comment: [Done.](http://jsfiddle.net/pYJm6/1/) Now how I can put the yellow pane as the back of the red one?

Comment: @J.Morais - I'm using Firefox, so I added CSS for the -moz styles. I also changed your animation to only iterate once instead of infinitely. I moved the perspective style to a parent element. It opens once, but then shuts again. We'll need to keep debugging. (http://jsfiddle.net/RustyTheBoyRobot/pYJm6/29/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the solution that I've played with:

1. Create a style that does the rotation animation.
2. Create a style for the end result of the animation (basically the same as your `to` section in the animation style.
3. Create a button or trigger to add the rotation style to your `<div>`
4. Set a timeout in JavaScript for the same duration as your animation.
5. Once the timeout triggers, remove the animation style and add the end result style

[Here's a modification of your jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RustyTheBoyRobot/pYJm6/81/). Getting the back side to work had a few quirks. The backside has to be positioned so that its right edge lines up with the front side's left edge. Then, you must rotate the back side -180 degrees so that it starts out behind the front page. Also, I had to switch the z-indexes once the animation had reached the midpoint.

All of this is hard to explain here, so I devoted [an entire blog post](http://newtroniccity.wordpress.com/2012/06/02/css3-rotations/) to it. I created a bunch of visuals to help make it clear.

Comment: Can you show some code? The main problem is that I don't know how to work with CSS transitions...

Comment: @J.Morais - I would rather not just hand you code; I want to help you learn. I found this site(http://www.the-art-of-web.com/css/css-animation/) which has some good examples. If you don't understand concepts, put that in your question so we can help you learn better. If you've tried something, put that in your question so we can help you see what went wrong.

Comment: There's a little problem: the yellow pane just appears, not rotate in the back of the red pane. The efect I want is similar to [this one](http://css3playground.com/flip-card.php). Any idea?

Comment: The best I can get is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/pYJm6/87/), which just switches the z-index; in order to figure out how they did it so smoothly I would have to go through their code line by line.

Comment: I tried to change some values, and the orientation to learn more about css animation, but I can't understand your 'hack' to invert the back panel. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/2Newd/2/) is my work. As you can see, the inside-left panel is inverted. Can you explain what you did with the yellow pane? I know that you made it 100px higher, but I can't figure out why.

Comment: @J.Morais I edited my answer with more clarification. Hopefully that helps you understand how I managed the yellow pane.

Answer (score 4):

There's also a more simple solution to work with; instead of switching z-indexes with a timer, you just need to specifiy that elements have no backside (`-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden`), and flip the yellow card 180 degrees, so its back touches the red backside.

This way, you only need to flip the container containing oth the yellow and red cards, which can be done by adding a class (e.g. `class="card opened"`).

Here's your example code with these changes:
http://jsfiddle.net/pYJm6/90/

Comment: Nice answer; I didn't know about backface-visibility.